# Set keywords in VBA based on multiple columns with dynamic ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I need to set some keywords based on multiple columns. I currently use this code which works well for one column:

```
Dim Words As range
Set Words = Sheets("Words").range("A2").Resize(Sheets("Words").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
```

But if I extend this to, say, A:AT it doesn't work.

Basically all I want to do is store all the words in ranges A2:Ax all the way to AT2:ATx but the issue is that each column has a different number of words that need to be stored.

EDIT: As requested, my full code as it currently stands

```
Sub Keyword()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Words As range
Dim strText As range
Dim c As range
Dim r As range

Set Words = Sheets("Words").range("A2:AT2").Resize(Sheets("Words").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)

Set strText = Sheets("Verbatims").range("BJ2").Resize(Sheets("Verbatims").range("BJ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
For Each c In strText
    For Each r In Words
        If InStr(1, UCase(c), UCase(r), 1) > 0 Then
            c.Offset(, 29) = c.Offset(, 29) & ", " & r
        End If
    Next r
    If Len(c.Offset(, 29)) > 0 Then c.Offset(, 29) = Right(c.Offset(, 29), (Len(c.Offset(, 29)) - 2))
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

EDIT2: Thanks to @jamheadart I've updated my code and it works now.

```
Sub Keywords()

Dim WordsRange As range
Dim hRow As Long
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("Words")
    For i = 1 To 46
        If hRow < Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row Then hRow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    Next i
    Set WordsRange = range("A2:AT" & hRow)
End With

Dim c As range
Dim Words As Collection
Set Words = New Collection

For Each c In WordsRange
    If c.Value <> "" Then Words.Add c.Value
Next

Dim strText As range
Dim x As range
Dim r As Variant

Set strText = Sheets("Verbatims").range("BJ2").Resize(Sheets("Verbatims").range("BJ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)
For Each x In strText
    For Each r In Words
        If InStr(1, UCase(x), UCase(r), 1) > 0 Then
            x.Offset(, 29) = x.Offset(, 29) & ", " & r
        End If
    Next r
    If Len(x.Offset(, 29)) > 0 Then x.Offset(, 29) = Right(x.Offset(, 29), (Len(x.Offset(, 29)) - 2))
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Would `Set Words = Sheets("Words").range("A2:AT2").Resize(Sheets("Words").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1)` work? It's not entirely clear what you mean by "Keyword" and "Setting" them. It's also not clear what mean by "Extend this". Nor is it clear what you are doing with this range after setting the variable. Can you handle multiple columns being present in this range in your downstream code?

Comment: I suspect you need to find the highest row used from all your columns, in which case you could loop through columns A:AT to do so. Then use that highest row to define a range `"A2:AT" & highestRow`

Comment: These solutions don't really work because the code stores all the blank values and outputs "".

@JNevill basically what I'm trying to do is store keywords stated in the Words spreadsheet and then match these keywords to a column and output them next to the cell that contains that keyword.

Comment: You could set some logic to ignore "" i.e. blanks, I'm not sure there's a way to define a single range that has varying row heights... I'd be transferring my keywords to a List or an Array anyway, not cycling through the defined range each time.

Comment: I think getting the `word` range set the way that I or @jeeped does it below is the first step. Get the relevant range into a variable. THEN you need to loop through that range `For each wordCell in Words.cells` and add each value to an array (skipping if it's blank). Then you have a nice array of non-blank keywords. Please share downstream code so we can help further.

Comment: @JNevill I've added my full code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to loop through columns 1 to 46 (AT) and find the maximum row, I wouldn't normally rely on UsedRange because it can sometimes not register updates on sheets but I suspect you aren't writing a massive long thread.

```
Sub eh()
Dim WordsRange As Range
Dim hRow As Long
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 46
    If hRow < Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row Then hRow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
Next i
Set WordsRange = Range("A2:AT" & hRow)
MsgBox (WordsRange.Address)
End Sub
```

Maybes you then want to put everything that's not a "" in to a list of key words to check against rather than checking against the range?

```
Dim c as Range
Dim Words as Collection
For Each c In WordsRange
    If c.Value2 <> "" Then Words.Add c.Value2
Next
```

Comment: I get an error "Object variable or With block variable not set" for the second set of the code, specifically the `Words.Add c.Value` part

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add after `Dim Words as Collection` you'll need `Set Words = New Collection`

Comment: No probs! I hope you like the use of Collections etc. can be a lot neater to hold your important stuff in an array or collection rather than checking against worksheets each time - depends on the situation

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know about the Collections feature; I'll definitely keep this in mind for next time. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Dim Words As range
with workSheets("Words")
    with intersect(.range("A:AT"), .usedrange)
        Set Words = .resize(.rows.count-1, .columns.count).offset(1, 0)
    end with
end with
```

If you want to avoid blanks, create a Union.

```
Dim Words As range, i as long

with workSheets("Words")
    set words = .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup))
    for i=2 to .columns("AT").column
        set words = Union(words, .range(.cells(2, i), .cells(.rows.count, i).end(xlup))
    next i
end with
```

To cycle through that Union you will likely have to deal with the [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-areas-property-excel).

Comment: Thanks, but this code stores blank cells too. Is there a way to ignore those cells?

Comment: See addendum added above.

Comment: This code is giving me errors. I think it's because of the ". .cells" part?

Comment: `.Cells` has a prefix `.` to carry the parent worksheet from `with workSheets("Words")` into the cell reference. I don't actually see a `. .cells` part)

Comment: Sorry for the annoying comments, I'm pretty new at this. if I paste your code, in the     `set words = .range(.cells(2, "A"). .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup))` part the VBA editor highlights the period in front of the second `.cells` and gives an error message saying "Compile error: Expected: identifier or bracketed expression".

Comment: Thanks! It's still storing and outputting blanks though; but I think we're on the right path. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

may be you're after this

```
Dim Words As Range
With Worksheets("Words")
    With Intersect(.Range("A:AT"), .UsedRange)
        Set Words = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    End With
End With
```